# Create DialogFragment as anonymous class

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I got an app with a code like this:

```
builAlert = new DialogFragment() {
                    @Override
                    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }
```

The import is of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`

This worked fine in the past. Now when I need to get to this old code, I get a runtime error saying the DialogFragment should be a public static class.. but when I wrote this old code, it used many class members and methods which were not static...

Is there some way to keep the DialogFragment as an anonymous class and not make it a different static class?

Comment: You _might_ be able to get away with it if you can be _absolutely certain_ that nothing will happen that will cause the `DialogFragment` to be destroyed and restored while it's showing; e.g., `Activity` recreation upon a rotation, etc. The problem is, since it's an anonymous class, the `FragmentManager` won't be able to restore it, and it'll crash with an `InstantiationException`. You really shouldn't leave it as an anonymous class.

Comment: Must it be static?

Comment: If it's a nested class, yes. Otherwise it's the same problem; `FragmentManager` won't be able to instantiate it.